# An inequality for conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the following: suppose a sequence $\{X_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ of integrable r.v.'s and $\mathcal{F}_j^k$ the $\sigma$-field generated by $\{X_j, \ldots,X_k\}$, $1 \leq j \leq k$. If for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_{k+n}^{\infty}$, $|P(A|\mathcal{F}_1^k) – P(A)| \leq M P(A)$ a.s. for some constant $M$, then
$$|E(X_{k+n}|\mathcal{F}_1^k) – E(X_{k+n})| \leq M E|X_{k+n}| \quad \text{a.s.}$$
Any help or reference would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to approximate $X_{k+n}$ by a sequence of $\mathcal{F}_{k+n}$-measurable step functions...

Comment: Do you have the proof?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "have". I think that I know how to prove it (in this sense I "have" the proof), but I don't have a reference for it (in this sense I don't "have" a proof). Since you haven't shown any effort so far, I don't feel inclined to write it down